# Disable OS optimization for Samsung Magician

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I have a SamSung 830 128GB SSD And have [Samsung Magician 4.1](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html) running on Windows 8 x64 Pro.
Somehow I keep getting insufficient memory issues in Windows. I have 4GB and cannot upgrade my Dell XPS15. The windows taskmanager shows over 90% memory in use when the errors occur. Several programms crash and hang when the memory is full.
Before I enabled OS optimization, everything ran just fine.

There is no option in Samsung Magician, but how can I undo the OS optimization feature? I cannot even resize the window to make a screenshot of all settings.

I currently have:

- hibernation mode : enabled
- virtual memory : shortcut
- indexing service/search : enabled
- prefetch/superfetch : disabled
- write cache buffer : enabled
- write cache buffer flushing : enabled
- power options : shortcut
- system restore : shortcut

How can I undo the changes that Samsung Magician has made? I can only select an other preset scheme.

screenshot to show that there is no 'undo'. The refresh icon in the bottom is to refresh drive information.

[image: Samsung Magician 4.1]

Comment: Do you have a restore point created before optimization?

Comment: I thought there was both Tune and Untune "buttons" in the OS optimization screen. Is Untune not there anymore?

Comment: Sorry don't have a restore point. The app seems to reset the virtual memory again to 100mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool configured my pagefile size to 100 MB. I only have 4 GB and this gives me an unstable OS. Resetting the OS to manage the virtual memory itself resolved it.

Comment: Some 'Magician', this!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into "Maximum Performance" and press "Apply" it will set virtual memory back to default, or just change it back manually.

And, if that screenshot is yours, then prefetch/superfetch is still enabled. Just turn on and off those things in "Advanced" settings and push the buttons to the right for each choice.